# Change background color if the value of at least one of ten cells drops too low

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In my sheet I have ten cells, representing the number of copies I have for ten book titles I'm selling. I want to make it so that if the value of one or more among those ten cells drops below `2`, another cell with my name in it will turn red, so I know if I need to restock at just a glance.

Any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ten cells are A1:A10, please select the cell with your name in it, Format, Conditional formatting...,  **Custom formula is** :

```
=min(A1:A10)<2
```

select Background Colour: red, <kbd>Save rules</kbd>.